# Maximizing chance that randomly drawn numbers fill a row or column

Tags: probability, puzzle, maximum-likelihood

This is just a problem I have thought of.

Let us say we have a square matrix of dimension $n$ with possible entries $1, 2, 3,..., n^2$ and we can freely distribute the entries in the matrix, each one has to be used exactly once.

The numbers then are drawn without replacement.

The probability that number $k$ is drawn is $0 \leq P(k) \leq 1$ with $\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}P(k)=1$

Now, we know the probabilities of the draws before we fill in our matrix. Let us say we sorted them such that $0 \leq p_1 \leq p_2 \leq ... \leq p_{n^2}$. We want to cheat and optimally distribute the numbers in order to minimize the expected number of draws until we cross out a whole row or column.

Is this a known problem? Is there an optimal strategy on how to distribute the probabilities $p_i$ in our matrix to minimize the expected number of draws until we cross out a whole row or column, and what is one such strategy?

---

I was thinking of determining the expected value of number of draws to get a certain number (then determine expected draws to get whole rows and columns and minimize those), but I do not think I can define it only given the $P(k)$, I would need to define how they change after each draw.

I was thinking that it is reasonable to remodel the probabilities after each draw for nonzero $P(k)$. 
Let us call $D$ the set of already drawn numbers. Then for $k \notin D$ with $P(k)\neq 0$ we do
 $$P'(k)=\frac{P(k)}{1-\sum_{ d \in D}P(d)}$$

But it sounds horribly complex!

Then again, it shouldn't matter, because if we have some remaining nonzero probabilities, their new probabilities are in the same order, that is if $P(k) \geq P(l)$ and both were not drawn, then $P'(k) \geq P'(l)$.

Comment: To win normal Bingo, you have to complete a row/column faster than other players.  That's a subtly different problem than e.g. minimizing your own completion time, esp. if you can look at the other players' grids before filling in your own.  If we ignore that subtlety, though, just minimizing your own completion time is still a great math problem.  For $n=2$ I imagine the best answer is ${1 \,\, 2 \choose 3\,\,  4}$, but for higher $n$...  would it actually depend on the values?  Fascinating...  (Also if you had included the diagonals, the added asymmetry makes things much more complicated.)

Comment: @antkam Your proposed solution for $n=2$ surely is not optimal for $P(1)=P(4)=0$ and $P(2)=P(3)=0.5$, as it is not possible to get a row or a colum full. Did you mean the $p_i$ as the entries?

Comment: haha, yes, i was lazy but i meant $p_i$ i.e. ${p_1 \,\,\, p_2 \choose p_3 \,\,\, p_4}$

Comment: Oh yeah, the $P'(k)$ you defined - this problem (even without the Bingo aspects) is called something like "unequal probability sampling without replacement" and is not easy.  Google it and you will see.

Comment: I have just edited! I think this is not important, but this stands in the way of calculating concrete expected values.

Comment: @antkam Do you see any way how to "dumb down" the problem? Maybe this partial solution would point in the right direction. This seems horribly hard, but if we make all probabilities equal it becomes trivial... nothing inbetween.

Comment: I've been playing with a toy example: 3x3 grid, just 5 numbers (or: 9 numbers but 4 of them have probability $\approx 0$ so they are always drawn after the 5). And among the 5, one of them (say 5) is (almost) always drawn first, so you put in in the center. How do you arrange the other 4?  Even in this case, I havent convinced myself that grouping them $(p_5, p_4, p_3),(p_5,p_2,p_1)$ is the best for any choice of $p_5 \gg p_4 \ge p_3 \ge p_2 \ge p_1$. I'd be very surprised if there are counter-examples, but the algebraic manipulation is just hairy enough that I can't do it while driving.  :)

Comment: @B.Swan I don't get the problem. How do you win? If a row or column is all chosen? After how many draws?

Comment: yeah @B.Swan - now that you have a bounty, maybe you should more clearly state a specific question.  e.g. how to arrange the $p_i$ to minimize finish time?

Comment: @mathworker21 You win if a row or a column is all chosen, as soon as the last missing number was drawn. The question is how to arrange the numbers (knowing their draw probabilities) in order to win in as few draws as possible.

Comment: @B.Swan I edited to make the problem much more bearable to read. In particular, I could not look at the phrase "maximize our chances of winning" anymore, as it makes no sense.

Comment: Also, of course there is an optimal strategy on how to distribute the probabilities? Each distribution yields an expected value for the minimum number of draws until a row or column is filled, so there is some (maybe many) distributions yielding that minimum. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mathworker21 That is fine, all is asked is AN optimal strategy, that is one (of perhaps many) optimal distributions. I think that two optimal solutions will be related, like having the same rows or columns (with probabilities as entries). I suspect everything else would change the expected number of draws, but I am unsure.

Comment: @B.Swan I am still confused. **What is your question?** In the post, you asked "is there an optimal distribution?" The answer, as I said in my last comment, is "yes".

Comment: @mathworker21 I want to know an optimal way to arrange the numbers depending on their probabilities.

Comment: @B.Swan I downvoted because you're not asking what you want to ask in the main problem.

Comment: @mathworker21 "Is there an optimal strategy on how to distribute the probabilities pi in our matrix to minimize the expected number of draws until we cross out a whole row or column?" is not clear enough?

Comment: @B.Swan I honestly do now know if you're trolling. I'm not trying to be rude; I genuinely don't know. I've made it very clear that the answer is "yes, there is an optimal strategy".

Comment: Ok, I understand. Will edit accordingly.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that all of the positions of the probabilities $p_i$ are already pre-assigned before any draws, and the actual entries are irrelevant? If $1$ goes in the top-left corner with probability $p_i$, you could replace $1$ with anything, and if the probability remains the same, the result doesn't change?

Comment: @CosmoVibe The probabilities are assigned before any draws. The probabilities are the probabilities of the number being drawn, not where it goes in the matrix! Numbers with the same probabilities of course can be swapped in the matrix, as it should not change the expected value of draws needed. So instead of asking to distribute the numbers, we ask to distribute the $p_i$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something at first glance. If $p_i$ are pre-assigned and draws are without replacement, how do they work exactly? For example, lets say $p_k=\{1/2,1/3,1/6\}$. Lets say we draw $k=1$ that had $p_1=1/2$ in first draw. Now in the second draw, we have $1/3$ to draw $k=2$ and $1/6$ to draw $k=3$, and $1-1/2-1/3=1/2$ to draw... nothing?

Comment: To add on to my previous comment; Now I see you suggest $P'(k)$'s as new probabilities after each draw to model the unequal drawing without replacement. But in your problem statement, you do not mention how $P'(k)$'s is modeled exactly? - So your question is, how to find the strategy, knowing the initial $p_k$'s (which are initially sorted), and that the new $P'(k)$'s  after each draw, are generally somehow modeled as the new probabilities such that they remain sorted as initially (they are maintained in the same $p_k$'s order)?

Comment: Then as you mentioned, expressing probabilities of drawing entire rows/columns gets complex, and does not look easy to minimize. I would suggest trying to model it and run it as a simulation.

Comment: @Vepir I have written about remodeling the probabilities after each draw, although that is not necessary, because the remodeling leaves the order untouched. You can imagine that we randomly sample from the interval $[0,1]$ and assign a subinterval of length $p_k$ to each number. If we draw a number, we simply remove the according subinterval and sample from the remaining intervals.

Comment: @Vepir I am working on that